# NoneType has no attribute .format

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement, string-formatting

I connect to a sqlite database and want to perform this peace of code on the selection.

```
import langid
...#connecter etc. to database
languagedata = []
connector = sqlite3.connect("GERMANY.db")
selecter = connector.cursor()
selecter.execute(''' SELECT title FROM DATAGERMANY''') #select only the title
for row in selecter: #iterate through all the rows in db
    languagedata.append(row) #append to list
    if languagedata is not None: #check weather datatype is None or not
        print (langid.classify("{}")).format(languagedata[-1]) #-1 for always take the last appended attribute of the list
    else:
        continue #if datatype is none, continue with next one
```

I started of without the if statement. That gave me the following errormessage:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'`.

So I added the if statement to check weather the data is of type `None` or not.
It works now for the first "round" of iteration. It takes the first attribute of the list and passes it to `langid`. But afterwards I get the same error message as above.

What am I doing wrong?

Note that not all the `rows` will come back with data. Some of them wont have data in them.

Comment: Looks like `print (langid.classify("{}")).format(languagedata[-1])` must be `print (langid.classify("{}.format(languagedata[-1]")))`

Comment: Oh mate. Thank you so much. I was freaking out over here why that did not work! Could you write that as an answer?

Comment: @Christoph Good observation. Can be hard to catch these kind of errors sometimes.

Comment: Yep. Thank god there is this page that someone who has not stared at this code for a couple of hours can find these typos.

Comment: @Christoph Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like statement in your code:

`print (langid.classify("{}")).format(languagedata[-1])`

must be

`print (langid.classify("{}.format(languagedata[-1]")))`

More on string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)